# CloudKit Query Value Limit Error

Tags: nspredicate, cloudkit

I have a query with a predicate in which I want to see if any values inside an array are contained in a CKRecord on CloudKit, but when I execute the query I get an error saying "Query filter exceeds the limit of values: 250 for container"

Is there another way to query my array? It has 500 objects in it, but it's dynamic so depending on the user it could be a lot less or a lot more.

```
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PhoneNumber == %@", numbers1];
        CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"PhoneNumbers" predicate:predicate];
        [publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"%@", results);

            }
}];
```

Comment: Use `CKQueryOperation`. Search on examples and review the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987).

Comment: Don't know if its an option, but you could simple put all your numbers into a Blob of data and save it as an Asset. Use core data with predicates subsequent to extraction to get the subset you want.

Comment: I'm seeing strange behaviour where I see that same error if there are over 250 but if there are any number above about 140 I see internal server error. Then using less than 140 it works.